# Checking ipv4 & ipv6 forwarding in C for Linux and FreeBSD

Tags: linux, ipv6, freebsd, forwarding, ipv4

I am trying to figure out whether forwarding is allowed (necessary for my app). I need to check for both Linux and FreeBSD. Unfortunately uncle G didn't return any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sysctl` to read `net.inet.ip.forwarding` on BSD, and `net.ipv4.ip_forward` (or `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding`, they're synonyms) and `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding` on Linux.